# NodeJs Synchronous MYSQL Query and Foreach

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise

I have some mysql Query's in NodeJs that depends to a above result. Here is my code:

```
const sms = async function() {  
await connection.query('select * from sms where sms.status_id = 2',
    (err, rows) => {
      if (err) throw err
        rows.forEach(row => {
            startdate = moment(row.statdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
            enddate = moment(row.enddate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');                
            connection.query('select * from positions where sms_id = "'+row.id+'" and verified is null order by date asc',
                (err, rows2) => {
                   if (err) throw err
                   rows2.forEach(row2 => {
                        connection.query('HERE IS A QUERY TO INSERT A REGISTER IN ANOTHER TABLE', data, (err,res) => {
                            if (err) throw err
                            console.log(`Inserted ${res.insertId}`);
                        })
                   })
                }
            ); 
        })
    }
)
```

The problem is, that way, I don't have the expected result in the middle query.

How can i do this synchronous?

I try to use Promises, but i don't understand how to do.

Comment: An important missing piece of the puzzle is [how to promisify functions that accept a nodeback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22519785/3478010).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, you should avoid synchronous functions, especially if running server operations.
Rather, I'd recommend using [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) and it's [promise wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper).

Then you can do:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
...

// use promise, then, catch

const sms = async function() {  
  return connection.query('select * from sms where sms.status_id = 2')
    .then(([smss]) =>
      smss.map(row => {
        connection.query('select * from positions where sms_id = "'+row.id+'" and verified is null order by date asc')
          .then(([positions]) => positions)) // unwrap array
    )
    .then(positions => 
      positions.map(row => connection.query('...'))
    )
    .catch(e => {
      // process errors
    });
};

// or use awaits

const sms = async () => {
  let [smss] = await connection.query('select * from sms where sms.status_id = 2');
  let positions = await Promise.all(smss.map(row => {
    ... 
  });
};
```

---

Alternatively, you can use some better SQL queries to simplify the process. Like this:

```sql
select *
from sms
join positions on (positions.sms_id = sms.id)
where sms.status_id = 2
  and positions.verified is null
order by positions.date
```

Comment: It didn't work. Returns:
(node:61661) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

Comment: Then catch the error using the .catch() and past what is says